# Protractor tests fail because value is empty, not when using protractor live mode

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to get e2e tests up and running in my Angular 2 app, but somehow the following test just doesn't want to succeed:

```
it('Title should be ALGEMEEN', () => {
    console.log('I am going to sleep for 5 seconds');
    browser.sleep(5000)
    var title = element(by.css('#sidebar-menu')).element(by.id('title'));
    console.log('This is my value for title.getText()');
    console.log(title.getText());

    browser.wait(function() {
        return title.isPresent();
    }, 5000);

    expect(title.getText()).toEqual('ALGEMEEN');

});
```

Protractor returns:

> Expected '' to equal 'ALGEMEEN'.

This is strange, because when I use protractor in the live mode, and just type element(by.css('#sidebar-menu')).element(by.id('title')).getText() in my terminal I do get 'ALGEMEEN' returned.

Do you guys maybe have any idea what is going wrong? This is what is logged in my console when I output title.getText() ([pastebin url](http://pastebin.com/RPsCKw8P)).